# Was is the angle needed to see a glory (a rainbow-like effect) from space off the Earth?

Tags: light, atmospheric-effects, spectra

What positions would the Earth, Sun and viewer need to be to see a glory (a rainbow-like effect) from space?

What position would they need to be in to reproduce this picture?

[image: glory seen by MODIS]

Source: [Gizmodo](https://www.gizmodo.com.au/2012/06/wow-its-a-double-rainbow-from-space/) ([NASA](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/IOTD/view.php?id=78380) via [Universe Today](https://www.universetoday.com/95995/pacific-glory/))

Related:

- https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16308/rainbow-dynamics
- https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34357/rainbow-space-probe

Comment: That's not a rainbow, that's a glory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glory_(optical_phenomenon)

Comment: The satellite takes a image at an angle, then the image is processed to make it appear that the satellite is looking straight down. In the processing, any circles get distorted. Rainbows are always 42 degrees (on Earth). That's not a rainbow.

Comment: Since the word "rainbow" has multiple meanings it's best to call it what it seems to be, a glory. The spread of colors it produces can be called a "rainbow-like effect" for example. I've adjusted the wording to avoid the confusion. But I think this question is about an atmospheric effect seen in an Earth-observing satellite and doesn't involve Astronomy at all, so I think it's off-topic here but an excellent question in Earthscience SE. Why not move it now before someone posts an answer and you can't delete it?

Comment: double rainbow! [original](https://youtu.be/OQSNhk5ICTI) and [extra crispy](https://youtu.be/MX0D4oZwCsA)

Comment: I think the question is more about viewing geometry than about the atmospheric optics mechanism.

Comment: From the Wikipedia link it seems that a glory can be seen around the shadow of the observer. Thus, if not the mechanism, the geometry of observation seems straightforward.

Comment: @uhoh a double rainbow glory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A glory is a rainbow-colored bullseye appearing directly opposite the Sun due to diffraction by water droplets of a certain size.
From an airplane, you can sometimes see this effect surrounding the airplane's shadow.
As the [NASA article](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/images/78380/a-glorious-view) explains, the polar orbiting [Terra](https://terra.nasa.gov/about) satellite's scan pattern transformed the circular rings into elongated ovals.